# I want to load a CSV from a local directory into Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, csv

I can create a dummy string in my code and parse into an array but there is a disconnect for me as to how I load a CSV from a local directory and convert it to a string that I can then load into an array to parse...

Here is my code so far:

```
Var itemArray = [];

var dummyString:String = "Item 1    Item 2    Item 3\nItem 4    Item 5    Item 6";

parse(dummyString, itemArray);

function parse(string, array) {
    //code
}
```

So instead of passing in a dummy string I would like to load a csv file from a local directory like this: file:///Volumes/localDir/subDir/file.csv

I know how to browse and select it but don't know how to get it into a format that I can parse... If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library which worked well for my needs:

http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use the csvlib... If I use the example code I get errors: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:CSV." and "Call to a possibly undefined method CSV."  I don't need to be connected to the internet to be able to use the csvlib do I?